# Creat a Log window in Python

Tags: python, logging

I want  a script in python which opens a logger window when the test is running and the output I want to see will be pushed to the logger window. I found baisc GUI script using wxpython but I dont know how to push my output to the gui being opened. Can anyone help me?

My Code:

```
import wx
import thread
import threading

class ExamplePanel(wx.Panel):        
        def __init__(self, parent):
            wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
            self.quote = wx.StaticText(self, label="Your Log :", pos=(10, 10))

            self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(0,40), size=(1100,1100), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)
        def append_txt(self,txt):
            self.logger.AppendText(txt)




def sample_Window():
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = wx.Frame(None)
    panel = ExamplePanel(frame)
    frame.Show()
    panel.append_txt("Log Starts Here\n First line of code \n Second line of code ")
    app.MainLoop()

sample_Window()
```

Once I give the app.Mainloop I am not able give further input to the appendtext method. I got suggestions to use threading to run the append_txt as a separate thread to pass the argument but i am not sure how to do it. My goal is call a method and pass on the text as argument which will show the text in logger window.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way to do it is to embed your task into the panel, and start it with a thread:

```
import wx
import thread
import threading
import time

class ExamplePanel(wx.Panel):        
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.quote = wx.StaticText(self, label="Your Log :", pos=(10, 10))

        self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(0,40), size=(1100,1100), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)

        ########################################################################
        # Use a thread to start your task
        ########################################################################
        task_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.my_task, args = ())
        task_thread.setDaemon(True)
        task_thread.start()

    def append_txt(self,txt):
        self.logger.AppendText(txt)

    def my_task(self):
        ########################################################################
        # Do your job right here and update log
        ########################################################################
        for i in range(100):
            self.append_txt('\nNew line added(No.%s)' % (i + 1))

            time.sleep(1)


def sample_Window():
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = wx.Frame(None)
    panel = ExamplePanel(frame)
    frame.Show()
    panel.append_txt("Log Starts Here\n First line of code \n Second line of code ")
    app.MainLoop()

sample_Window()
```

**Update:**

Well, here's another way to do it:

```
import wx
import thread
import threading
import time

class ExamplePanel(wx.Panel):        
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.quote = wx.StaticText(self, label="Your Log :", pos=(10, 10))

        self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(0,40), size=(1100,1100), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)

    def append_txt(self,txt):
        self.logger.AppendText(txt)

def sample_Window():
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = wx.Frame(None)
    panel = ExamplePanel(frame)
    frame.Show()
    panel.append_txt("Log Starts Here\n First line of code \n Second line of code ")

    ############################################################################
    # Use thread to update logs
    ############################################################################
    task_thread = threading.Thread(target=my_task, args=(panel, ))
    task_thread.setDaemon(True)
    task_thread.start()

    app.MainLoop()

def my_task(panel):
    ############################################################################
    #  Do your job right here and update log
    ############################################################################
    for i in range(100):
        panel.append_txt('\nNew line added(No.%s)' % (i + 1))

        time.sleep(1)

sample_Window()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I want the object of class "ExamplePanel" to expose the method "append_txt" so that I can call this module wherever I want and once i pass arguments to the "append_txt" it will push the txt to logger window

Comment: As per the code I can only insert my code under my_task method.  But I want this whole code to be a module and i should be able to import it in another module and use its method to update the log. Is it possible?

Comment: No, you can't do that. The way GUI works is pretty much event-driven, and once you handed over the control to a GUI, you need an event(mouse click or whatever change that can be captured by the window you setup) to trigger an operation. The only way to do what you want is through a long running task started before hand.