# wxpython display type list

Tags: python, wxpython

I am reading some csv data files and trying to display the data.
If I read them in by row I can display the data by line to a wx.TextCtrl .
If I read the data in as a list :

```
exampleFile = open('example.csv')
exampleReader = csv.reader(exampleFile)
exampleData = list(exampleReader)
print (exampleData)
self.logger.AppendText(exampleData)
```

The print works fine, but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: TextEntry.AppendText(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
```

What is the preferred way to display list data in wxPython?

Answer (score 3):

With help of @Shane answer at [Creat a Log window in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758536/creat-a-log-window-in-python) I made a sample for you.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import wx
import threading
import time

class ExamplePanel(wx.Panel):        
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.quote = wx.StaticText(self, label="Your Log :", pos=(10, 10))

        self.logger = wx.TextCtrl(self, pos=(0,40), size=(1100,1100), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)

        ########################################################################
        # Use a thread to start your task
        ########################################################################
        task_thread = threading.Thread(target = self.my_task, args = ())
        task_thread.setDaemon(True)
        task_thread.start()




    def append_txt(self,txt):
        self.logger.AppendText(txt)

    def my_task(self):
        ########################################################################
        # Do your job right here and update log
        ########################################################################
        exampleFile = open('example.csv')
        exampleReader = csv.reader(exampleFile)    
        # exampleData = list(exampleReader)
        print (exampleData)
        self.logger.AppendText('CSV output : \n' )
        self.logger.AppendText('\n'.join(map(str,exampleData)))
        '''for i in range(100):
            self.append_txt('\nNew line added(No.%s)' % (i + 1))

            time.sleep(1)
        '''


def sample_Window():
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = wx.Frame(None)
    panel = ExamplePanel(frame)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

sample_Window()
```

Your specific answer of code is :

```
exampleFile = open('example.csv')
exampleReader = csv.reader(exampleFile)    
# exampleData = list(exampleReader)
print (exampleData)
self.logger.AppendText('CSV output : \n' )
self.logger.AppendText('\n'.join(map(str,exampleData)))
```

and [image: screenshot of output result]

and my example csv content is :

```
Col1,Col2
1,2
M,N
```

Cheers.

Comment: That did it.THANKS !

Comment: @user3005949 You're welcome, if you got your answer, please accept it.